# is freelancing a job or a business?

Tags: halal-haram

I am currently availing a Scholarship which has bound me not to do any other job.I want to marry and Scholarship money is not enough for married life. I want to start freelancing and if it is a job then I will break the contract. someone said that freelancing is a business. It is like you are a shopkeeper and sell your skills to a wide range of people. some say they hire you it means you are doing a job. I am really confused. kindly clear if it is halal for me or not?